# Flip SVG but not text inside

Tags: html, css, svg

Is it possible to flip the SVGs in the DIV "Analytics" but not the text? Ive managed to flip the DIV by just using `-webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);` and
`transform: scaleX(-1);`but obviously now the text is unreadable. Is it possible to keep the text unflipped or no?

```html
<style>
#analytics-dashboard{
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
  
  .analytics{
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
  transform: scaleX(-1);
  }

.small-piece{
   transform: translate(-95px);
   opacity: 0;
  animation: intoplace2 1s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes intoplace2{
  0%{
    transform: translate(-95px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50%{
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100%{
    transform: translate(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.large-piece{
  transform: translate(-40px);
  opacity: 0;
  animation: intoplace1 1s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes intoplace1{
  0%{
    transform: translate(-60px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  35%{
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100%{
    transform: translate(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.restart{
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
    .analytics0{fill:#D3D3D3;}
    .analytics1{fill:#828282;}
    .analytics2{fill:#B0B0B0;}
    .analytics3{fill:#EAEAEB;}
    .analytics4{fill:#F6F6F7;}
    .analytics5{opacity:0.7;fill:url(#SVGID_1_);enable-background:new    ;}
    .analytics6{fill:#373737;}
    .analytics7{opacity:0.6;fill:url(#SVGID_2_);enable-background:new    ;}
    .analytics8{opacity:0.5;fill:url(#SVGID_3_);enable-background:new    ;}
    .analytics9{opacity:0.3;fill:#F1CF32;enable-background:new    ;}
    .analytics10{fill:#F1CF32;}
    .analytics11{opacity:0.3;fill:#E9B231;enable-background:new    ;}
    .analytics12{fill:#E9B231;}
    .analytics13{opacity:0.3;fill:#DB822E;enable-background:new    ;}
    .analytics14{fill:#DB822E;}
    .analytics15{fill:#FFFFFF;}
    .analytics16{fill:#D1D1D1;}
    .analytics17{fill:#959595;}
    .analytics18{fill:#AEAEAE;}
    .analytics19{fill:#E9E9E9;}
    .analytics20{fill:#D9812D;}
    .analytics21{opacity:0.5;fill:#D8802E;enable-background:new    ;}
    .analytics22{fill:#D8802E;}
    .analytics23{fill:none;stroke:#FFB502;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .analytics24{fill:none;stroke:#FF8403;stroke-width:4;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .analytics25{fill:none;stroke:#FFD100;stroke-width:4;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
</style>

  <div class="analytics">

<svg version="1.1" id="analytics-dashboard" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     x="0px" y="0px" width="550px" height="524px" viewBox="0 0 550 524" style="enable-background:new 0 0 550 524;"
     xml:space="preserve">

<g class="large-piece">
    <path class="analytics0" d="M115.2,3.5l9.7-3.1c2.2-0.7,4.5-0.4,6.5,0.7l345.3,199.4c1.5,0.9,2.7,2.1,3.5,3.5l-8.3,4.8l0,0L115.2,3.5z"/>
    <path class="analytics1" d="M481.4,208.6v304.6c0,2.3-1.2,4.3-3.1,5.5l-7.9,4.7l1.5-314.7l8.3-4.8C480.9,205.3,481.4,207,481.4,208.6z"/>
    <path class="analytics2" d="M476.7,200.4c1.5,0.9,2.7,2.1,3.5,3.5s1.2,3,1.2,4.7v1.7l-7.8,3.4h-11.2l4.5-10l7.6-4.5L476.7,200.4z"/>
    <path class="analytics3" d="M111.9,309.8l361.7,208.8V215.4c0-4.8-2.5-9.2-6.7-11.6L120.5,3.8c-3.8-2.2-8.6,0.6-8.6,5V309.8z"/>
    <polygon class="analytics4" points="111.9,82 473.6,290.8 473.6,290 111.9,81.2   "/>
    <polygon class="analytics4" points="111.9,106.3 473.6,315.2 473.6,314.4 111.9,105.5     "/>
    <polygon class="analytics4" points="111.9,130.7 473.6,339.5 473.6,338.7 111.9,129.9     "/>
    <polygon class="analytics4" points="111.9,155 473.6,363.9 473.6,363.1 111.9,154.2   "/>
    <polygon class="analytics4" points="111.9,179.4 473.6,388.2 473.6,387.4 111.9,178.6     "/>
    <polygon class="analytics4" points="111.9,203.7 473.6,412.5 473.6,411.7 111.9,202.9     "/>
    
        <linearGradient id="SVGID_1_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="1492.1595" y1="1252.473" x2="1428.5929" y2="1362.5734" gradientTransform="matrix(-1 0 0 -1 1765.928 1574)">
        <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#DB822E"/>
        <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#F1CF32"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <path class="analytics5" d="M473.6,388.2c0,0-3.1,8.3-17.8-0.2c-14.8-8.5-21.2-44.6-46-59c-24.8-14.3-20.1-1-34.3-9.6
        c-14.2-8.6-20.7-73.5-36.6-82.7c-16-9.2-21.3,48.4-46.1,35c-24.8-13.4-39-108.5-60.3-120.8s-44,80.8-63.8,76.5
        c-40.6-8.8-56.8-87-56.8-87v86.9l361.7,209.6L473.6,388.2L473.6,388.2z"/>
    <path class="analytics6" d="M118.6,323.2l346.4,200c3.8,2.2,8.6-0.5,8.6-4.9v-83L111.9,226.5v85.1C111.9,316.4,114.4,320.8,118.6,323.2z"
        />
    
        <linearGradient id="SVGID_2_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="1488.6642" y1="1252.1271" x2="1436.686" y2="1342.1558" gradientTransform="matrix(-1 0 0 -1 1765.928 1574)">
        <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#DB822E"/>
        <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#F1CF32"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <path class="analytics7" d="M473.6,418.7c0,0-26.9-22.8-42.5-60.7s-32.5-56.1-49.4-65.8c-22.2-12.7-36.3,6.4-58.5-5.5
        s-26.6-73.7-40.8-81.9c-14.2-8.2-17.7,82.2-37.2,73s-21.3-61.1-44.3-76.5s-21.6,27.2-42.9,15.9c-21.2-11.2-46.1-62.3-46.1-62.3
        v71.5l361.7,208.8L473.6,418.7L473.6,418.7z"/>
    
        <linearGradient id="SVGID_3_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="1460.4933" y1="1235.7115" x2="1437.0006" y2="1276.4022" gradientTransform="matrix(-1 0 0 -1 1765.928 1574)">
        <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#F1CF32"/>
        <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#DB822E"/>
    </linearGradient>
    
    <path class="analytics12" d="M300.3,386.4L300.3,386.4L300.3,386.4L300.3,386.4L300.3,386.4L300.3,386.4c0.1,10.3,6.3,23,14.9,30
        c4.5,3.6,9,5.2,12.8,4.8l-0.7-1.7c-4.3,0.4-9.6-2-14.4-6.8c-6.8-6.8-11.2-17.1-11.3-25.5c0.1-9.5,5.8-14.6,13.8-11.9
        c0.9,0.3,1.8,0.7,2.7,1.2V375c-1.9-1-3.9-1.7-5.8-2C305.1,371.9,300.4,377.4,300.3,386.4z M301.6,387.1L301.6,387.1
        c0-1-1.3-1.7-1.3-0.7l0,0C300.3,385.4,301.6,386.1,301.6,387.1z"/>
    <path class="analytics13" d="M180.4,316.1c0.1,10.3,6.3,23,14.9,30c7.5,6,15.3,6.5,19.3,1.1c4-5.5,3.4-16-1.5-25.9s-13.4-17.6-20.7-18.6
        C185.2,301.7,180.5,307.1,180.4,316.1z M181.7,316.9c0.1-9.5,5.8-14.6,13.8-11.9c7.1,2.4,14.4,10.5,18.1,19.9
        c3.7,9.4,3.1,18.6-1.6,22.4c-4.6,3.8-12.3,1.8-19.1-5C186.2,335.6,181.7,325.3,181.7,316.9z"/>
    <path class="analytics14" d="M192.5,302.7c1.9,0.3,3.8,1,5.8,2v1.5c-0.9-0.5-1.9-0.9-2.8-1.2c-8-2.7-13.7,2.4-13.8,11.9
        c0.1,8.5,4.5,18.7,11.3,25.5c6.7,6.8,14.5,8.8,19.1,5c3.9-3.2,5-10.3,3-18.1l1.2,0.2c1.8,7.1,1.4,13.8-1.6,17.7
        c-4,5.4-11.8,4.9-19.3-1.1c-8.6-6.9-14.9-19.7-14.9-30C180.5,307.1,185.2,301.7,192.5,302.7z"/>

    <path class="analytics10" d="M436.9,466.7c-1.6-0.9-2.4-2.5-2.4-5s0.8-3.1,2.4-2.2s2.4,2.5,2.4,5C439.3,466.9,438.5,467.6,436.9,466.7z
         M435.2,462.1c0,0.5,0,1,0.1,1.3c0.1,0.4,0.2,0.7,0.3,1c0.1,0.3,0.3,0.5,0.4,0.7c0.2,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.4,0.5s0.3,0.2,0.5,0.3
        c0.2,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.2c0.1,0,0.3,0.1,0.4,0c0.2,0,0.3-0.1,0.4-0.3c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.4,0.3-0.7c0.1-0.3,0.1-0.7,0.1-1.2
        c0-0.6-0.1-1.1-0.2-1.6s-0.2-0.9-0.4-1.1c-0.2-0.3-0.3-0.5-0.5-0.7s-0.4-0.3-0.6-0.4s-0.4-0.2-0.6-0.3c-0.2,0-0.3,0-0.5,0.1
        s-0.3,0.3-0.4,0.7C435.3,461.1,435.2,461.5,435.2,462.1z"/>
    <path class="analytics10" d="M440.2,463.5c0-0.4,0-0.7,0.1-0.9c0.1-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.3-0.4c0.1-0.1,0.3-0.1,0.4,0c0.1,0,0.3,0.1,0.4,0.2
        c0.3,0.2,0.7,0.5,0.9,1c0.3,0.4,0.4,1,0.4,1.7c0,0.4,0,0.7-0.1,0.9c-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3,0.4c-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.1-0.4,0.1
        s-0.3-0.1-0.4-0.2c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4-0.3c-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.5s-0.3-0.5-0.3-0.8C440.2,464.2,440.2,463.9,440.2,463.5z
         M440.9,462.7c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.4-0.2,1c0,0.5,0.1,1,0.2,1.2s0.3,0.5,0.6,0.6c0.3,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.6,0.1s0.2-0.4,0.2-1s-0.1-1-0.2-1.2
        c-0.2-0.3-0.3-0.5-0.6-0.6C441.3,462.7,441.1,462.6,440.9,462.7z M441.3,469.1l3.8-4.9l0.6,0.3l-3.8,4.9L441.3,469.1z M444.2,469.8
        c-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.7-0.1-1c0-0.4,0-0.7,0.1-0.9c0.1-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.3-0.4c0.1-0.1,0.3-0.1,0.4-0.1s0.3,0.1,0.4,0.2s0.3,0.2,0.4,0.3
        c0.1,0.1,0.3,0.3,0.4,0.5s0.2,0.5,0.3,0.8c0.1,0.3,0.1,0.7,0.1,1c0,0.4,0,0.7-0.1,0.9c-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3,0.4
        c-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.1-0.4,0.1s-0.3-0.1-0.4-0.2s-0.3-0.2-0.4-0.3c-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.5C444.4,470.4,444.3,470.2,444.2,469.8z
         M444.8,468.1c-0.2,0.1-0.2,0.4-0.2,1c0,0.5,0.1,1,0.2,1.2s0.3,0.5,0.6,0.6c0.3,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.6,0.1s0.2-0.4,0.2-1s-0.1-1-0.2-1.2
        c-0.2-0.3-0.3-0.5-0.6-0.6C445.2,468,445,468,444.8,468.1z"/>
    <path class="analytics10" d="M310.1,392.2l0.3-3.1l3.1,1.8v0.7l-2.5-1.5l-0.2,2c0.3,0.1,0.7,0.3,1.2,0.5c0.3,0.1,0.5,0.3,0.7,0.5
        s0.4,0.4,0.6,0.7c0.2,0.3,0.3,0.6,0.5,1c0.1,0.4,0.2,0.8,0.2,1.2c0,0.4-0.1,0.8-0.2,1c-0.1,0.3-0.3,0.4-0.5,0.4s-0.4,0-0.6,0
        c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.7-0.3c-0.7-0.4-1.3-0.9-1.7-1.4v-0.8c0.4,0.6,1,1,1.7,1.4c0.2,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.6,0.3c0.2,0,0.3,0,0.4,0
        s0.2-0.1,0.2-0.2c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.1-0.3c0-0.1,0-0.3,0-0.4c0-0.3,0-0.6-0.1-0.9s-0.2-0.4-0.3-0.6c-0.1-0.2-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.4
        s-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.3c-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.3-0.8-0.3c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.1-0.5-0.1h-0.2L310.1,392.2z"/>
    <path class="analytics10" d="M315.1,395.1l0.3-3.1l3.1,1.8v0.7L316,393l-0.2,2c0.3,0.1,0.7,0.3,1.2,0.5c0.3,0.1,0.5,0.3,0.7,0.5
        s0.4,0.4,0.6,0.7c0.2,0.3,0.3,0.6,0.5,1c0.1,0.4,0.2,0.8,0.2,1.2s-0.1,0.8-0.2,1c-0.1,0.3-0.3,0.4-0.5,0.4s-0.4,0-0.6,0
        c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.7-0.3c-0.7-0.4-1.3-0.9-1.7-1.4v-0.8c0.4,0.6,1,1,1.7,1.4c0.2,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.6,0.3c0.2,0,0.3,0,0.4,0
        s0.2-0.1,0.2-0.2c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.1-0.3c0-0.1,0-0.3,0-0.4c0-0.3,0-0.6-0.1-0.9s-0.2-0.4-0.3-0.6c-0.1-0.2-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.4
        s-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.3c-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.3-0.8-0.3c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.1-0.5-0.1h-0.2L315.1,395.1z"/>
    <path class="analytics10" d="M319.9,396.6c0-0.4,0-0.7,0.1-0.9c0.1-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.3-0.4s0.3-0.1,0.4,0c0.1,0,0.3,0.1,0.4,0.2
        c0.3,0.2,0.7,0.5,0.9,1c0.3,0.4,0.4,1,0.4,1.7c0,0.4,0,0.7-0.1,0.9c-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3,0.4c-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.1-0.4,0.1
        s-0.3-0.1-0.4-0.2s-0.3-0.2-0.4-0.3s-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.5s-0.3-0.5-0.3-0.8C320,397.3,319.9,397,319.9,396.6z M320.6,395.9
        c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.4-0.2,1s0.1,1,0.2,1.2s0.3,0.5,0.6,0.6c0.3,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.6,0.1s0.2-0.4,0.2-1c0-0.5-0.1-1-0.2-1.2
        s-0.3-0.5-0.6-0.6C321,395.8,320.8,395.8,320.6,395.9z M321,402.3l3.8-4.9l0.6,0.3l-3.8,4.9L321,402.3z M324,403
        c-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.7-0.1-1c0-0.4,0-0.7,0.1-0.9c0.1-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.3-0.4c0.1-0.1,0.3-0.1,0.4-0.1s0.3,0.1,0.4,0.2
        c0.2,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.4,0.3c0.1,0.1,0.3,0.3,0.4,0.5s0.2,0.5,0.3,0.8c0.1,0.3,0.1,0.7,0.1,1c0,0.4,0,0.7-0.1,0.9
        c-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3,0.4c-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.1-0.4,0.1s-0.3-0.1-0.4-0.2c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4-0.3s-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.5
        C324.1,403.5,324,403.3,324,403z M324.6,401.2c-0.2,0.1-0.2,0.4-0.2,1s0.1,1,0.2,1.2s0.3,0.5,0.6,0.6c0.3,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.6,0.1
        s0.2-0.4,0.2-1c0-0.5-0.1-1-0.2-1.2s-0.3-0.5-0.6-0.6S324.7,401.1,324.6,401.2z"/>
    <path class="analytics14" d="M190.2,318.8V318l4.1,2.4v0.7l-2.6,4.8l-0.7-0.4l2.6-4.8L190.2,318.8z"/>
    <path class="analytics14" d="M197.3,329.3c-1.6-0.9-2.4-2.5-2.4-5c0-2.4,0.8-3.1,2.4-2.2c1.6,0.9,2.4,2.5,2.4,5
        C199.7,329.4,198.9,330.2,197.3,329.3z M195.6,324.7c0,0.5,0,1,0.1,1.3c0.1,0.4,0.2,0.7,0.3,1s0.3,0.5,0.4,0.7
        c0.2,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.4,0.5c0.1,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.3c0.2,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.2c0.1,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.4,0c0.2,0,0.3-0.1,0.4-0.3
        c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.4,0.3-0.7c0.1-0.3,0.1-0.7,0.1-1.2c0-0.6-0.1-1.1-0.2-1.6s-0.2-0.9-0.4-1.1c-0.2-0.3-0.3-0.5-0.5-0.7
        s-0.4-0.3-0.6-0.4c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.6-0.3c-0.2,0-0.3,0-0.5,0.1s-0.3,0.3-0.4,0.7C195.6,323.6,195.6,324.1,195.6,324.7z"/>
    <path class="analytics14" d="M200.6,326c0-0.4,0-0.7,0.1-0.9c0.1-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.3-0.4s0.3-0.1,0.4,0c0.1,0,0.3,0.1,0.4,0.2
        c0.3,0.2,0.7,0.5,0.9,1c0.3,0.4,0.4,1,0.4,1.7c0,0.4,0,0.7-0.1,0.9c-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3,0.4s-0.3,0.1-0.4,0.1
        c-0.1,0-0.3-0.1-0.4-0.2c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4-0.3s-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.5c-0.1-0.2-0.3-0.5-0.3-0.8C200.7,326.7,200.6,326.4,200.6,326z
         M201.3,325.3c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.4-0.2,1c0,0.5,0.1,1,0.2,1.2c0.2,0.3,0.3,0.5,0.6,0.6s0.4,0.2,0.6,0.1c0.2-0.1,0.2-0.4,0.2-1
        s-0.1-1-0.2-1.2c-0.2-0.3-0.3-0.5-0.6-0.6C201.7,325.2,201.5,325.2,201.3,325.3z M201.7,331.7l3.8-4.9l0.6,0.3l-3.8,4.9
        L201.7,331.7z M204.6,332.4c-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.7-0.1-1c0-0.4,0-0.7,0.1-0.9c0.1-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.3-0.4s0.3-0.1,0.4-0.1
        c0.1,0,0.3,0.1,0.4,0.2c0.2,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.4,0.3s0.3,0.3,0.4,0.5c0.1,0.2,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.8s0.1,0.7,0.1,1c0,0.4,0,0.7-0.1,0.9
        c-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3,0.4s-0.3,0.1-0.4,0.1c-0.1,0-0.3-0.1-0.4-0.2c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4-0.3s-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.5
        C204.8,332.9,204.7,332.7,204.6,332.4z M205.2,330.6c-0.2,0.1-0.2,0.4-0.2,1c0,0.5,0.1,1,0.2,1.2c0.2,0.3,0.3,0.5,0.6,0.6
        s0.4,0.2,0.6,0.1c0.2-0.1,0.2-0.4,0.2-1c0-0.5-0.1-1-0.2-1.2c-0.2-0.3-0.3-0.5-0.6-0.6C205.6,330.6,205.4,330.5,205.2,330.6z"/>
    <path class="analytics10" d="M374.2,439.5v-0.7c0.3,0.4,0.6,0.8,1,1s0.6,0.3,0.8,0.1c0.2-0.1,0.3-0.4,0.3-0.9v-4.4l0.6,0.3v4.5
        c0,0.4,0,0.7-0.1,0.9c-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.4,0.4s-0.3,0-0.5,0s-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.2C374.9,440.3,374.5,439.9,374.2,439.5z"/>
    <path class="analytics10" d="M377.6,440.3c0-0.2,0-0.4,0.1-0.5s0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.4-0.1s0.3,0,0.4,0.1s0.3,0.1,0.4,0.2
        c0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.3,0.2c0.1,0,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1l0.6,0.4c0-0.4-0.1-0.8-0.3-1.1c-0.2-0.3-0.5-0.6-0.9-0.8c-0.4-0.3-0.8-0.4-1.2-0.4
        v-0.7c0.4,0.1,0.8,0.2,1.2,0.4c0.6,0.3,1,0.7,1.3,1.2s0.4,1.1,0.4,1.7v1.4c0,0.3-0.1,0.5-0.2,0.7s-0.3,0.2-0.5,0.2
        s-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.1c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.2c-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4-0.3c-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4-0.4s-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.5s-0.2-0.4-0.3-0.6
        C377.7,440.8,377.6,440.5,377.6,440.3z M378.2,440.6c0,0.6,0.4,1.1,1.1,1.5l0,0c0.7,0.4,1.1,0.3,1.1-0.3V441
        c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.3-0.7-0.5C378.7,440,378.2,440,378.2,440.6z"/>
    <path class="analytics10" d="M381.9,444.2v-4.4c0.5,0,1.1,0.2,1.7,0.5c0.5,0.3,0.9,0.7,1.2,1.1c0.3,0.5,0.4,1,0.4,1.5v3.1l-0.6-0.3v-3.1
        c0-0.1,0-0.3,0-0.4s-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.4c-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.3-0.5c-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.3-0.6-0.4c-0.3-0.2-0.7-0.3-1-0.4v4L381.9,444.2z"/>
    <path class="analytics10" d="M386.1,444.7v-2.8l0.6,0.3v2.8c0,0.5,0.1,0.9,0.3,1.2c0.2,0.3,0.4,0.6,0.8,0.8c0.4,0.2,0.7,0.3,0.8,0.2
        c0.2-0.1,0.3-0.4,0.3-0.9v-2.8l0.6,0.3v2.8c0,0.7-0.2,1.1-0.4,1.3c-0.3,0.2-0.7,0.1-1.2-0.2c-0.5-0.3-1-0.7-1.2-1.3
        C386.2,445.9,386.1,445.3,386.1,444.7z"/>
    <path class="analytics10" d="M390.2,447.5c0-0.2,0-0.4,0.1-0.5s0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.4-0.1s0.3,0,0.4,0.1
        c0.1,0,0.3,0.1,0.4,0.2c0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.3,0.2c0.1,0,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1l0.6,0.4c0-0.4-0.1-0.8-0.3-1.1c-0.2-0.3-0.5-0.6-0.9-0.8
        c-0.4-0.3-0.8-0.4-1.2-0.4v-0.7c0.4,0.1,0.8,0.2,1.2,0.4c0.6,0.3,1,0.7,1.3,1.2s0.4,1.1,0.4,1.7v1.4c0,0.3-0.1,0.5-0.2,0.7
        s-0.3,0.2-0.5,0.2s-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.1c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.2c-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4-0.3c-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4-0.4s-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.5
        s-0.2-0.4-0.3-0.6C390.2,448.1,390.2,447.8,390.2,447.5z M390.8,447.9c0,0.6,0.4,1.1,1.1,1.5l0,0c0.7,0.4,1.1,0.3,1.1-0.3v-0.9
        c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.3-0.7-0.5C391.3,447.2,390.8,447.3,390.8,447.9z"/>
    <path class="analytics10" d="M394.4,451.4V447c0.6,0.1,1.3,0.3,2,0.7v0.6c-0.4-0.3-0.9-0.4-1.4-0.5v3.9L394.4,451.4z"/>
    <path class="analytics10" d="M396.7,448l0.6,0.3l1.1,4.4l1.2-3.1l0.6,0.3l-1.7,4.3c-0.3,0.8-0.7,1-1.3,0.6c-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4-0.3V454
        c0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.3,0.3c0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3,0c0.1,0,0.2-0.1,0.3-0.2c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.2-0.3c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.1-0.3v-0.1
        L396.7,448z"/>
    <path class="analytics15" d="M250.8,345.8c0-0.6,0.2-1.1,0.5-1.4s0.9-0.2,1.7,0.1v-1.4l0.6,0.3v1.4c0.6,0.4,1.2,0.9,1.8,1.6v1
        c-0.6-0.7-1.1-1.2-1.8-1.6v3.1c0.3,0.3,0.6,0.6,0.8,0.9s0.4,0.5,0.7,0.9c0.3,0.3,0.4,0.7,0.5,1.1s0.2,0.8,0.2,1.2
        c0,0.7-0.2,1.1-0.6,1.3c-0.4,0.2-1,0.1-1.7-0.2v1.4l-0.6-0.3v-1.4c-0.8-0.5-1.5-1.1-2.1-1.9v-1.1c0.6,0.8,1.3,1.5,2.1,2v-3.5
        c-0.3-0.3-0.5-0.5-0.7-0.6s-0.3-0.3-0.6-0.6c-0.2-0.3-0.4-0.5-0.5-0.7s-0.2-0.5-0.3-0.8C250.8,346.3,250.8,346,250.8,345.8z
         M251.6,346.2c0,0.3,0.1,0.7,0.3,1s0.6,0.7,1,1.1v-2.9C252.1,345.1,251.6,345.4,251.6,346.2z M253.6,353.2c1,0.4,1.4,0.2,1.4-0.6
        c0-0.5-0.1-0.9-0.4-1.3c-0.3-0.4-0.6-0.8-1.1-1.3L253.6,353.2L253.6,353.2z"/>
    <path class="analytics15" d="M257.3,351.3l0.4-4l4,2.3v1l-3.3-1.9l-0.2,2.6c0.4,0.1,1,0.3,1.5,0.6c0.3,0.2,0.6,0.4,0.9,0.6
        s0.5,0.5,0.8,0.9c0.3,0.3,0.4,0.8,0.6,1.2c0.2,0.5,0.2,1,0.2,1.6c0,0.5-0.1,1-0.2,1.3c-0.2,0.3-0.3,0.5-0.6,0.5
        c-0.3,0.1-0.5,0.1-0.8,0s-0.5-0.2-0.9-0.4c-0.9-0.5-1.6-1.1-2.2-1.8v-1c0.6,0.7,1.3,1.4,2.2,1.9c0.3,0.2,0.6,0.3,0.8,0.3
        c0.2,0,0.4,0,0.5,0c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3c0.1-0.2,0.1-0.3,0.1-0.4s0-0.3,0-0.5c0-0.4,0-0.8-0.1-1.1c-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.6-0.4-0.8
        c-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.4-0.5-0.5c-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.3-0.6-0.4c-0.3-0.2-0.7-0.4-1-0.5s-0.5-0.2-0.6-0.2H258L257.3,351.3z"/>
    <path class="analytics15" d="M266.5,361.7c-2-1.2-3.1-3.3-3.1-6.4s1-4.1,3.1-2.9c2,1.2,3.1,3.3,3.1,6.4
        C269.6,361.9,268.6,362.8,266.5,361.7z M264.3,355.7c0,0.6,0,1.2,0.1,1.7s0.2,1,0.3,1.3c0.1,0.3,0.3,0.7,0.5,0.9
        c0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.6s0.4,0.3,0.6,0.4s0.4,0.2,0.6,0.3c0.2,0.1,0.4,0.1,0.6,0s0.4-0.2,0.5-0.3c0.1-0.2,0.3-0.5,0.3-0.9
        s0.1-1,0.1-1.6c0-0.8-0.1-1.5-0.2-2.1s-0.3-1.1-0.5-1.5s-0.5-0.7-0.7-0.9c-0.2-0.2-0.5-0.4-0.8-0.6s-0.6-0.3-0.8-0.3
        s-0.4,0-0.7,0.1c-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.4-0.5,0.9C264.4,354.3,264.3,354.9,264.3,355.7z"/>
    <path class="analytics15" d="M271,359.2l0.4-4l4,2.3v1l-3.3-1.9l-0.2,2.6c0.4,0.1,1,0.3,1.5,0.6c0.3,0.2,0.6,0.4,0.9,0.6s0.5,0.5,0.8,0.9
        c0.3,0.3,0.4,0.8,0.6,1.2c0.2,0.5,0.2,1,0.2,1.6c0,0.5-0.1,1-0.2,1.3c-0.2,0.3-0.3,0.5-0.6,0.5c-0.3,0-0.5,0.1-0.8,0
        s-0.5-0.2-0.9-0.4c-0.9-0.5-1.6-1.1-2.2-1.8v-1c0.6,0.7,1.3,1.4,2.2,1.9c0.3,0.2,0.6,0.3,0.8,0.3s0.4,0,0.5,0
        c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3s0.1-0.3,0.1-0.4s0-0.3,0-0.5c0-0.4,0-0.8-0.1-1.1s-0.2-0.6-0.4-0.8c-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.4-0.5-0.5
        c-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.3-0.6-0.4c-0.3-0.2-0.7-0.4-1-0.5s-0.5-0.2-0.6-0.2h-0.2L271,359.2z"/>
    <path class="analytics15" d="M277.5,367.9v-1.1l0.8,0.5v1.1L277.5,367.9z"/>
    <path class="analytics15" d="M283,371.2c-2-1.2-3.1-3.3-3.1-6.4s1-4.1,3.1-2.9c2,1.2,3.1,3.3,3.1,6.4S285.1,372.4,283,371.2z M280.8,365.2
        c0,0.6,0,1.2,0.1,1.7s0.2,1,0.3,1.3c0.1,0.3,0.3,0.7,0.5,0.9c0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.6c0.2,0.2,0.4,0.3,0.6,0.4s0.4,0.2,0.6,0.3
        c0.2,0.1,0.4,0.1,0.6,0c0.2,0,0.4-0.2,0.5-0.3c0.1-0.2,0.3-0.5,0.3-0.9c0.1-0.4,0.1-1,0.1-1.6c0-0.8-0.1-1.5-0.2-2.1
        s-0.3-1.1-0.5-1.5s-0.5-0.7-0.7-0.9c-0.2-0.2-0.5-0.4-0.8-0.6s-0.6-0.3-0.8-0.3c-0.2,0-0.4,0-0.7,0.1c-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.4-0.5,0.9
        C280.9,363.8,280.8,364.5,280.8,365.2z"/>
    <path class="analytics15" d="M286.9,370.6v-1l3.7-3.2l1,0.5v5.5l1.1,0.6v0.9l-1.1-0.6v2.7l-0.8-0.5v-2.7L286.9,370.6z M287.9,370.2
        l2.8,1.6v-4L287.9,370.2z"/>
    <path class="analytics12" d="M252.1,368.7v-6.4l3.3,1.9v0.6l-2.7-1.6v2.2l2.4,1.4v0.7l-2.4-1.4v2.9L252.1,368.7z"/>
    <path class="analytics12" d="M255.8,368.5L255.8,368.5L255.8,368.5c0-1.7,0.6-2.2,1.8-1.5c0.3,0.1,0.5,0.3,0.7,0.5s0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6
        c0.1,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.3,0.7c0.1,0.3,0.2,0.4,0.2,0.6s0.1,0.3,0.1,0.6c0,0.2,0,0.3,0,0.4v0.2v0.3l-3-1.7c0,0.5,0.2,0.9,0.4,1.3
        c0.2,0.3,0.5,0.6,1,0.9c0.6,0.3,1,0.5,1.4,0.4v0.7c-0.4,0-0.9-0.2-1.4-0.5l0,0c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.3-0.6-0.5s-0.4-0.4-0.6-0.7
        c-0.2-0.3-0.3-0.6-0.4-1C255.8,369.4,255.8,369,255.8,368.5z M256.3,368.6l2.4,1.4c0-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.4c0-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.6
        c-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.3-0.7c-0.2-0.3-0.4-0.4-0.7-0.6c-0.4-0.2-0.7-0.3-0.9-0.1C256.5,367.7,256.4,368,256.3,368.6z"/>
    <path class="analytics12" d="M260.1,371.9v-5.2l0.6,0.3v1.9c0.3,0.1,0.7,0.2,1,0.4c0.2,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.3s0.3,0.3,0.5,0.5
        s0.3,0.4,0.4,0.7c0.1,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.9c0.1,0.3,0.1,0.7,0.1,1.1s0,0.8-0.1,1c-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.4-0.3,0.5c-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.2-0.4,0.2
        s-0.3,0-0.5-0.1s-0.3-0.1-0.4-0.2c-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.3-0.8-0.6c-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.4-0.5-0.6s-0.2-0.3-0.3-0.5c-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.4
        C260.1,372.1,260.1,372,260.1,371.9z M260.7,372.2c0,0.6,0.3,1,1.1,1.5c0.2,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.4,0.2s0.3,0,0.4,0s0.2-0.2,0.3-0.4
        c0.1-0.2,0.1-0.5,0.1-1c0-0.6-0.1-1.1-0.3-1.5c-0.2-0.4-0.5-0.7-1-1c-0.3-0.2-0.7-0.3-1-0.3V372.2L260.7,372.2z"/>
    <path class="analytics12" d="M264.3,375.7v-4.4c0.6,0.1,1.3,0.3,2,0.7v0.6c-0.4-0.3-0.9-0.4-1.4-0.5v3.9L264.3,375.7z"/>
    <path class="analytics12" d="M266.8,375.2v-2.8l0.6,0.3v2.8c0,0.5,0.1,0.9,0.3,1.2c0.2,0.3,0.4,0.6,0.8,0.8c0.4,0.2,0.7,0.3,0.8,0.2
        c0.2-0.1,0.3-0.4,0.3-0.9V374l0.6,0.3v2.8c0,0.7-0.2,1.1-0.4,1.3c-0.3,0.2-0.7,0.1-1.2-0.2c-0.5-0.3-1-0.7-1.2-1.3
        C267,376.4,266.8,375.8,266.8,375.2z"/>
    <path class="analytics12" d="M270.9,378.1c0-0.2,0-0.4,0.1-0.5s0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.4-0.1s0.3,0,0.4,0.1s0.3,0.1,0.4,0.2
        s0.3,0.1,0.3,0.2c0.1,0,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1l0.6,0.4c0-0.4-0.1-0.8-0.3-1.1c-0.2-0.3-0.5-0.6-0.9-0.8c-0.4-0.3-0.8-0.4-1.2-0.4v-0.7
        c0.4,0.1,0.8,0.2,1.2,0.4c0.6,0.3,1,0.7,1.3,1.2s0.4,1.1,0.4,1.7v1.4c0,0.3-0.1,0.5-0.2,0.7s-0.3,0.2-0.5,0.2s-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.1
        c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.2c-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4-0.3c-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4-0.4s-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.5s-0.2-0.4-0.3-0.6
        C270.9,378.6,270.9,378.4,270.9,378.1z M271.5,378.4c0,0.6,0.4,1.1,1.1,1.5l0,0c0.7,0.4,1.1,0.3,1.1-0.3v-0.9
        c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.3-0.7-0.5C272,377.8,271.5,377.8,271.5,378.4z"/>
    <path class="analytics12" d="M275.1,382v-4.4c0.6,0.1,1.3,0.3,2,0.7v0.6c-0.4-0.3-0.9-0.4-1.4-0.5v3.9L275.1,382z"/>
    <path class="analytics12" d="M277.4,378.6l0.6,0.3l1.1,4.4l1.2-3.1l0.6,0.3l-1.7,4.3c-0.3,0.8-0.7,1-1.3,0.6c-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4-0.3
        v-0.6c0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.3,0.3c0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3,0c0.1,0,0.2-0.1,0.3-0.2c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.2-0.3c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.1-0.3v-0.1
        L277.4,378.6z"/>
    <path class="analytics15" d="M131.6,277.7c0-0.6,0.2-1.1,0.5-1.4s0.9-0.2,1.7,0.1V275l0.6,0.3v1.4c0.6,0.4,1.2,0.9,1.8,1.6v1
        c-0.6-0.7-1.1-1.2-1.8-1.6v3.1c0.3,0.3,0.6,0.6,0.8,0.9s0.4,0.5,0.7,0.9c0.3,0.3,0.4,0.7,0.5,1.1s0.2,0.8,0.2,1.2
        c0,0.7-0.2,1.1-0.6,1.3c-0.4,0.2-1,0.1-1.7-0.2v1.4l-0.6-0.3v-1.4c-0.8-0.5-1.5-1.1-2.1-1.9v-1.1c0.6,0.8,1.3,1.5,2.1,2v-3.5
        c-0.3-0.3-0.5-0.5-0.7-0.6c-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.3-0.6-0.6c-0.2-0.3-0.4-0.5-0.5-0.7s-0.2-0.5-0.3-0.8C131.6,278.3,131.6,278,131.6,277.7
        z M132.4,278.2c0,0.3,0.1,0.7,0.3,1s0.6,0.7,1,1.1v-2.9C132.9,277.1,132.4,277.4,132.4,278.2z M134.4,285.1c1,0.4,1.4,0.2,1.4-0.6
        c0-0.5-0.1-0.9-0.4-1.3c-0.3-0.4-0.6-0.8-1.1-1.3L134.4,285.1L134.4,285.1z"/>
    <path class="analytics15" d="M137.5,279.7v-1l5.3,3.1v0.9l-3.3,6.3l-0.9-0.5l3.4-6.2L137.5,279.7z"/>
    <path class="analytics15" d="M143.9,291.1v-1c0.6,0.8,1.3,1.3,2,1.7s1.2,0.5,1.6,0.4c0.3-0.1,0.5-0.4,0.5-1s-0.2-1.1-0.5-1.6
        c-0.4-0.5-0.9-1-1.6-1.4l-0.9-0.5v-1l0.9,0.5c0.6,0.3,1,0.4,1.3,0.4c0.3-0.1,0.4-0.3,0.4-0.8s-0.2-0.9-0.5-1.4s-0.8-0.8-1.4-1.2
        c-0.6-0.3-1.1-0.5-1.7-0.5v-1c0.5,0,1.1,0.2,1.7,0.5l0,0c0.9,0.5,1.5,1.1,1.9,1.8c0.4,0.7,0.6,1.4,0.6,2.1c0,0.8-0.3,1.2-0.8,1.2
        h-0.2c0,0,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2s0.2,0.2,0.3,0.4s0.3,0.5,0.4,0.7c0.1,0.2,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.9c0.1,0.3,0.2,0.7,0.2,1s-0.1,0.6-0.2,0.9
        c-0.1,0.3-0.3,0.4-0.5,0.6c-0.2,0.1-0.5,0.2-0.9,0.1s-0.8-0.3-1.3-0.5C145.3,292.4,144.6,291.8,143.9,291.1z"/>
    <path class="analytics15" d="M150.4,294.8v-1c0.6,0.8,1.3,1.3,2,1.7c0.7,0.4,1.2,0.5,1.6,0.4c0.3-0.1,0.5-0.4,0.5-1s-0.2-1.1-0.5-1.6
        c-0.4-0.5-0.9-1-1.6-1.4l-0.9-0.5v-1l0.9,0.5c0.6,0.3,1,0.4,1.3,0.4c0.3-0.1,0.4-0.3,0.4-0.8s-0.2-0.9-0.5-1.4
        c-0.3-0.4-0.8-0.8-1.4-1.2c-0.6-0.3-1.1-0.5-1.7-0.5v-1c0.5,0,1.1,0.2,1.7,0.5l0,0c0.9,0.5,1.5,1.1,1.9,1.8
        c0.4,0.7,0.6,1.4,0.6,2.1c0,0.8-0.3,1.2-0.8,1.2h-0.2c0,0,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2c0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.3,0.4c0.2,0.2,0.3,0.5,0.4,0.7
        c0.1,0.2,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.9c0.1,0.3,0.2,0.7,0.2,1s-0.1,0.6-0.2,0.9c-0.1,0.3-0.3,0.4-0.5,0.6c-0.2,0.1-0.5,0.2-0.9,0.1
        s-0.8-0.3-1.3-0.5S151,295.5,150.4,294.8z"/>
    <path class="analytics15" d="M156.7,298.9v-1.1l0.8,0.5v1.1L156.7,298.9z"/>
    <path class="analytics15" d="M159.3,300.4v-0.9c0.4-0.1,0.8-0.3,1.2-0.4c0.4-0.2,0.8-0.4,1.3-0.7c0.4-0.3,0.8-0.6,1.1-1s0.4-0.9,0.4-1.3
        c0-1-0.6-1.9-1.8-2.6c-0.7-0.4-1.4-0.5-2-0.4V292c0.6-0.1,1.3,0.1,2.1,0.5c0.9,0.5,1.5,1.1,1.9,1.9c0.4,0.7,0.6,1.5,0.6,2.2
        c0,0.5-0.1,1-0.3,1.4s-0.5,0.8-0.9,1.1c-0.3,0.3-0.7,0.5-1.1,0.8c-0.3,0.2-0.7,0.4-1.1,0.5l3.5,2v1L159.3,300.4z"/>
    <path class="analytics15" d="M165,301v-1l3.7-3.2l1,0.5v5.4l1.1,0.6v0.9l-1.1-0.6v2.7l-0.8-0.5v-2.7L165,301z M165.9,300.6l2.8,1.6v-4
        L165.9,300.6z"/>
    <path class="analytics14" d="M132.9,300.7v-6.4l0.6,0.4l1.8,4.3l1.9-2.2l0.6,0.4v6.4l-0.6-0.3V298l-1.9,2.1l-1.9-4.4v5.2L132.9,300.7z"/>
    <path class="analytics14" d="M138.8,302.6c0-0.2,0-0.4,0.1-0.5s0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.4-0.1s0.3,0,0.4,0.1
        c0.1,0,0.3,0.1,0.4,0.2c0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.3,0.2c0.1,0,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1l0.6,0.4c0-0.4-0.1-0.8-0.3-1.1s-0.5-0.6-0.9-0.8
        c-0.4-0.3-0.8-0.4-1.2-0.4v-0.7c0.4,0.1,0.8,0.2,1.2,0.4c0.6,0.3,1,0.7,1.3,1.2s0.4,1.1,0.4,1.7v1.4c0,0.3-0.1,0.5-0.2,0.7
        c-0.1,0.2-0.3,0.2-0.5,0.2s-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.1c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.2c-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4-0.3s-0.3-0.2-0.4-0.4
        c-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.5s-0.2-0.4-0.3-0.6C138.8,303.1,138.8,302.9,138.8,302.6z M139.4,303c0,0.6,0.4,1.1,1.1,1.5l0,0
        c0.7,0.4,1.1,0.3,1.1-0.3v-0.9c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.3-0.7-0.5C139.9,302.3,139.4,302.4,139.4,303z"/>
    <path class="analytics14" d="M143,306.5v-4.4c0.6,0.1,1.3,0.3,2,0.7v0.6c-0.4-0.3-0.9-0.4-1.4-0.5v3.9L143,306.5z"/>
    <path class="analytics14" d="M145.3,305.5c0-0.5,0.1-0.9,0.2-1.1c0.1-0.3,0.3-0.4,0.5-0.5s0.4-0.1,0.6,0c0.2,0,0.4,0.1,0.7,0.3
        c0.4,0.2,0.8,0.5,1.2,1v0.6c-0.4-0.4-0.7-0.7-1.1-0.9c-0.5-0.3-0.8-0.3-1-0.2c-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.5-0.3,1.2c0,0.6,0.1,1.2,0.3,1.6
        s0.6,0.8,1,1s0.8,0.3,1.1,0.4v0.7c-0.4,0-0.8-0.2-1.2-0.4c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.5-0.3c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.3-0.5-0.5s-0.3-0.4-0.4-0.7
        c-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.3-0.9C145.4,306.2,145.3,305.9,145.3,305.5z"/>
    <path class="analytics14" d="M149.1,310.1v-6.6l0.6,0.3v2c0.4,0,0.8,0.2,1.2,0.4c0.5,0.3,0.9,0.7,1.1,1.2c0.3,0.5,0.4,1.1,0.4,1.7v2.8
        l-0.6-0.3v-2.8c0-0.9-0.3-1.5-1-1.9c-0.4-0.2-0.8-0.3-1.1-0.4v3.9L149.1,310.1z"/>

</g>
<g>
    <circle class="analytics23" cx="38.8" cy="76.8" r="7"/>
    <circle class="analytics23" cx="511.8" cy="465.8" r="5"/>
    <circle class="analytics24" cx="130.8" cy="470.8" r="10"/>
    <circle class="analytics25" cx="480.8" cy="69.8" r="10"/>
</g>
</svg>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to keep the text unflipped, but you probably do not want that. Be that as it may, you can keep a part of a figure grouped and transformed independently. In the example below, I added a group (`g`) with `id="noflip"`. You can then *undo* the transformation in that group. But in that case, it is not aligned with the rest. For the effect I believe you want, you also need to `skew` it:

```html
<style>
#analytics-dashboard{
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
  
  .analytics{
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(-1);
  }
#noflip{
  transform: scaleX(-1) skew(0, -50deg);
  transform-origin: center;
}

.small-piece{
   transform: translate(-95px);
   opacity: 0;
  animation: intoplace2 1s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes intoplace2{
  0%{
    transform: translate(-95px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50%{
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100%{
    transform: translate(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.large-piece{
  transform: translate(-40px);
  opacity: 0;
  animation: intoplace1 1s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes intoplace1{
  0%{
    transform: translate(-60px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  35%{
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100%{
    transform: translate(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.restart{
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
    .analytics0{fill:#D3D3D3;}
    .analytics1{fill:#828282;}
    .analytics2{fill:#B0B0B0;}
    .analytics3{fill:#EAEAEB;}
    .analytics4{fill:#F6F6F7;}
    .analytics5{opacity:0.7;fill:url(#SVGID_1_);enable-background:new    ;}
    .analytics6{fill:#373737;}
    .analytics7{opacity:0.6;fill:url(#SVGID_2_);enable-background:new    ;}
    .analytics8{opacity:0.5;fill:url(#SVGID_3_);enable-background:new    ;}
    .analytics9{opacity:0.3;fill:#F1CF32;enable-background:new    ;}
    .analytics10{fill:#F1CF32;}
    .analytics11{opacity:0.3;fill:#E9B231;enable-background:new    ;}
    .analytics12{fill:#E9B231;}
    .analytics13{opacity:0.3;fill:#DB822E;enable-background:new    ;}
    .analytics14{fill:#DB822E;}
    .analytics15{fill:#FFFFFF;}
    .analytics16{fill:#D1D1D1;}
    .analytics17{fill:#959595;}
    .analytics18{fill:#AEAEAE;}
    .analytics19{fill:#E9E9E9;}
    .analytics20{fill:#D9812D;}
    .analytics21{opacity:0.5;fill:#D8802E;enable-background:new    ;}
    .analytics22{fill:#D8802E;}
    .analytics23{fill:none;stroke:#FFB502;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .analytics24{fill:none;stroke:#FF8403;stroke-width:4;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .analytics25{fill:none;stroke:#FFD100;stroke-width:4;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
</style>

  <div class="analytics">

<svg version="1.1" id="analytics-dashboard" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     x="0px" y="0px" width="550px" height="524px" viewBox="0 0 550 524" style="enable-background:new 0 0 550 524;"
     xml:space="preserve">

<g class="large-piece">
    <path class="analytics0" d="M115.2,3.5l9.7-3.1c2.2-0.7,4.5-0.4,6.5,0.7l345.3,199.4c1.5,0.9,2.7,2.1,3.5,3.5l-8.3,4.8l0,0L115.2,3.5z"/>
    <path class="analytics1" d="M481.4,208.6v304.6c0,2.3-1.2,4.3-3.1,5.5l-7.9,4.7l1.5-314.7l8.3-4.8C480.9,205.3,481.4,207,481.4,208.6z"/>
    <path class="analytics2" d="M476.7,200.4c1.5,0.9,2.7,2.1,3.5,3.5s1.2,3,1.2,4.7v1.7l-7.8,3.4h-11.2l4.5-10l7.6-4.5L476.7,200.4z"/>
    <path class="analytics3" d="M111.9,309.8l361.7,208.8V215.4c0-4.8-2.5-9.2-6.7-11.6L120.5,3.8c-3.8-2.2-8.6,0.6-8.6,5V309.8z"/>
    <polygon class="analytics4" points="111.9,82 473.6,290.8 473.6,290 111.9,81.2   "/>
    <polygon class="analytics4" points="111.9,106.3 473.6,315.2 473.6,314.4 111.9,105.5     "/>
    <polygon class="analytics4" points="111.9,130.7 473.6,339.5 473.6,338.7 111.9,129.9     "/>
    <polygon class="analytics4" points="111.9,155 473.6,363.9 473.6,363.1 111.9,154.2   "/>
    <polygon class="analytics4" points="111.9,179.4 473.6,388.2 473.6,387.4 111.9,178.6     "/>
    <polygon class="analytics4" points="111.9,203.7 473.6,412.5 473.6,411.7 111.9,202.9     "/>
    
        <linearGradient id="SVGID_1_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="1492.1595" y1="1252.473" x2="1428.5929" y2="1362.5734" gradientTransform="matrix(-1 0 0 -1 1765.928 1574)">
        <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#DB822E"/>
        <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#F1CF32"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <path class="analytics5" d="M473.6,388.2c0,0-3.1,8.3-17.8-0.2c-14.8-8.5-21.2-44.6-46-59c-24.8-14.3-20.1-1-34.3-9.6
        c-14.2-8.6-20.7-73.5-36.6-82.7c-16-9.2-21.3,48.4-46.1,35c-24.8-13.4-39-108.5-60.3-120.8s-44,80.8-63.8,76.5
        c-40.6-8.8-56.8-87-56.8-87v86.9l361.7,209.6L473.6,388.2L473.6,388.2z"/>
    <path class="analytics6" d="M118.6,323.2l346.4,200c3.8,2.2,8.6-0.5,8.6-4.9v-83L111.9,226.5v85.1C111.9,316.4,114.4,320.8,118.6,323.2z"
        />
    
        <linearGradient id="SVGID_2_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="1488.6642" y1="1252.1271" x2="1436.686" y2="1342.1558" gradientTransform="matrix(-1 0 0 -1 1765.928 1574)">
        <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#DB822E"/>
        <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#F1CF32"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <path class="analytics7" d="M473.6,418.7c0,0-26.9-22.8-42.5-60.7s-32.5-56.1-49.4-65.8c-22.2-12.7-36.3,6.4-58.5-5.5
        s-26.6-73.7-40.8-81.9c-14.2-8.2-17.7,82.2-37.2,73s-21.3-61.1-44.3-76.5s-21.6,27.2-42.9,15.9c-21.2-11.2-46.1-62.3-46.1-62.3
        v71.5l361.7,208.8L473.6,418.7L473.6,418.7z"/>
    
        <linearGradient id="SVGID_3_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="1460.4933" y1="1235.7115" x2="1437.0006" y2="1276.4022" gradientTransform="matrix(-1 0 0 -1 1765.928 1574)">
        <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#F1CF32"/>
        <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#DB822E"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <g id='noflip'>
    <path class="analytics12" d="M300.3,386.4L300.3,386.4L300.3,386.4L300.3,386.4L300.3,386.4L300.3,386.4c0.1,10.3,6.3,23,14.9,30
        c4.5,3.6,9,5.2,12.8,4.8l-0.7-1.7c-4.3,0.4-9.6-2-14.4-6.8c-6.8-6.8-11.2-17.1-11.3-25.5c0.1-9.5,5.8-14.6,13.8-11.9
        c0.9,0.3,1.8,0.7,2.7,1.2V375c-1.9-1-3.9-1.7-5.8-2C305.1,371.9,300.4,377.4,300.3,386.4z M301.6,387.1L301.6,387.1
        c0-1-1.3-1.7-1.3-0.7l0,0C300.3,385.4,301.6,386.1,301.6,387.1z"/>
    <path class="analytics13" d="M180.4,316.1c0.1,10.3,6.3,23,14.9,30c7.5,6,15.3,6.5,19.3,1.1c4-5.5,3.4-16-1.5-25.9s-13.4-17.6-20.7-18.6
        C185.2,301.7,180.5,307.1,180.4,316.1z M181.7,316.9c0.1-9.5,5.8-14.6,13.8-11.9c7.1,2.4,14.4,10.5,18.1,19.9
        c3.7,9.4,3.1,18.6-1.6,22.4c-4.6,3.8-12.3,1.8-19.1-5C186.2,335.6,181.7,325.3,181.7,316.9z"/>
    <path class="analytics14" d="M192.5,302.7c1.9,0.3,3.8,1,5.8,2v1.5c-0.9-0.5-1.9-0.9-2.8-1.2c-8-2.7-13.7,2.4-13.8,11.9
        c0.1,8.5,4.5,18.7,11.3,25.5c6.7,6.8,14.5,8.8,19.1,5c3.9-3.2,5-10.3,3-18.1l1.2,0.2c1.8,7.1,1.4,13.8-1.6,17.7
        c-4,5.4-11.8,4.9-19.3-1.1c-8.6-6.9-14.9-19.7-14.9-30C180.5,307.1,185.2,301.7,192.5,302.7z"/>

    <path class="analytics10" d="M436.9,466.7c-1.6-0.9-2.4-2.5-2.4-5s0.8-3.1,2.4-2.2s2.4,2.5,2.4,5C439.3,466.9,438.5,467.6,436.9,466.7z
         M435.2,462.1c0,0.5,0,1,0.1,1.3c0.1,0.4,0.2,0.7,0.3,1c0.1,0.3,0.3,0.5,0.4,0.7c0.2,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.4,0.5s0.3,0.2,0.5,0.3
        c0.2,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.2c0.1,0,0.3,0.1,0.4,0c0.2,0,0.3-0.1,0.4-0.3c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.4,0.3-0.7c0.1-0.3,0.1-0.7,0.1-1.2
        c0-0.6-0.1-1.1-0.2-1.6s-0.2-0.9-0.4-1.1c-0.2-0.3-0.3-0.5-0.5-0.7s-0.4-0.3-0.6-0.4s-0.4-0.2-0.6-0.3c-0.2,0-0.3,0-0.5,0.1
        s-0.3,0.3-0.4,0.7C435.3,461.1,435.2,461.5,435.2,462.1z"/>
    <path class="analytics10" d="M440.2,463.5c0-0.4,0-0.7,0.1-0.9c0.1-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.3-0.4c0.1-0.1,0.3-0.1,0.4,0c0.1,0,0.3,0.1,0.4,0.2
        c0.3,0.2,0.7,0.5,0.9,1c0.3,0.4,0.4,1,0.4,1.7c0,0.4,0,0.7-0.1,0.9c-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3,0.4c-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.1-0.4,0.1
        s-0.3-0.1-0.4-0.2c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4-0.3c-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.5s-0.3-0.5-0.3-0.8C440.2,464.2,440.2,463.9,440.2,463.5z
         M440.9,462.7c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.4-0.2,1c0,0.5,0.1,1,0.2,1.2s0.3,0.5,0.6,0.6c0.3,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.6,0.1s0.2-0.4,0.2-1s-0.1-1-0.2-1.2
        c-0.2-0.3-0.3-0.5-0.6-0.6C441.3,462.7,441.1,462.6,440.9,462.7z M441.3,469.1l3.8-4.9l0.6,0.3l-3.8,4.9L441.3,469.1z M444.2,469.8
        c-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.7-0.1-1c0-0.4,0-0.7,0.1-0.9c0.1-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.3-0.4c0.1-0.1,0.3-0.1,0.4-0.1s0.3,0.1,0.4,0.2s0.3,0.2,0.4,0.3
        c0.1,0.1,0.3,0.3,0.4,0.5s0.2,0.5,0.3,0.8c0.1,0.3,0.1,0.7,0.1,1c0,0.4,0,0.7-0.1,0.9c-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3,0.4
        c-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.1-0.4,0.1s-0.3-0.1-0.4-0.2s-0.3-0.2-0.4-0.3c-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.5C444.4,470.4,444.3,470.2,444.2,469.8z
         M444.8,468.1c-0.2,0.1-0.2,0.4-0.2,1c0,0.5,0.1,1,0.2,1.2s0.3,0.5,0.6,0.6c0.3,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.6,0.1s0.2-0.4,0.2-1s-0.1-1-0.2-1.2
        c-0.2-0.3-0.3-0.5-0.6-0.6C445.2,468,445,468,444.8,468.1z"/>
    <path class="analytics10" d="M310.1,392.2l0.3-3.1l3.1,1.8v0.7l-2.5-1.5l-0.2,2c0.3,0.1,0.7,0.3,1.2,0.5c0.3,0.1,0.5,0.3,0.7,0.5
        s0.4,0.4,0.6,0.7c0.2,0.3,0.3,0.6,0.5,1c0.1,0.4,0.2,0.8,0.2,1.2c0,0.4-0.1,0.8-0.2,1c-0.1,0.3-0.3,0.4-0.5,0.4s-0.4,0-0.6,0
        c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.7-0.3c-0.7-0.4-1.3-0.9-1.7-1.4v-0.8c0.4,0.6,1,1,1.7,1.4c0.2,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.6,0.3c0.2,0,0.3,0,0.4,0
        s0.2-0.1,0.2-0.2c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.1-0.3c0-0.1,0-0.3,0-0.4c0-0.3,0-0.6-0.1-0.9s-0.2-0.4-0.3-0.6c-0.1-0.2-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.4
        s-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.3c-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.3-0.8-0.3c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.1-0.5-0.1h-0.2L310.1,392.2z"/>
    <path class="analytics10" d="M315.1,395.1l0.3-3.1l3.1,1.8v0.7L316,393l-0.2,2c0.3,0.1,0.7,0.3,1.2,0.5c0.3,0.1,0.5,0.3,0.7,0.5
        s0.4,0.4,0.6,0.7c0.2,0.3,0.3,0.6,0.5,1c0.1,0.4,0.2,0.8,0.2,1.2s-0.1,0.8-0.2,1c-0.1,0.3-0.3,0.4-0.5,0.4s-0.4,0-0.6,0
        c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.7-0.3c-0.7-0.4-1.3-0.9-1.7-1.4v-0.8c0.4,0.6,1,1,1.7,1.4c0.2,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.6,0.3c0.2,0,0.3,0,0.4,0
        s0.2-0.1,0.2-0.2c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.1-0.3c0-0.1,0-0.3,0-0.4c0-0.3,0-0.6-0.1-0.9s-0.2-0.4-0.3-0.6c-0.1-0.2-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.4
        s-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.3c-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.3-0.8-0.3c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.1-0.5-0.1h-0.2L315.1,395.1z"/>
    <path class="analytics10" d="M319.9,396.6c0-0.4,0-0.7,0.1-0.9c0.1-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.3-0.4s0.3-0.1,0.4,0c0.1,0,0.3,0.1,0.4,0.2
        c0.3,0.2,0.7,0.5,0.9,1c0.3,0.4,0.4,1,0.4,1.7c0,0.4,0,0.7-0.1,0.9c-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3,0.4c-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.1-0.4,0.1
        s-0.3-0.1-0.4-0.2s-0.3-0.2-0.4-0.3s-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.5s-0.3-0.5-0.3-0.8C320,397.3,319.9,397,319.9,396.6z M320.6,395.9
        c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.4-0.2,1s0.1,1,0.2,1.2s0.3,0.5,0.6,0.6c0.3,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.6,0.1s0.2-0.4,0.2-1c0-0.5-0.1-1-0.2-1.2
        s-0.3-0.5-0.6-0.6C321,395.8,320.8,395.8,320.6,395.9z M321,402.3l3.8-4.9l0.6,0.3l-3.8,4.9L321,402.3z M324,403
        c-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.7-0.1-1c0-0.4,0-0.7,0.1-0.9c0.1-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.3-0.4c0.1-0.1,0.3-0.1,0.4-0.1s0.3,0.1,0.4,0.2
        c0.2,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.4,0.3c0.1,0.1,0.3,0.3,0.4,0.5s0.2,0.5,0.3,0.8c0.1,0.3,0.1,0.7,0.1,1c0,0.4,0,0.7-0.1,0.9
        c-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3,0.4c-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.1-0.4,0.1s-0.3-0.1-0.4-0.2c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4-0.3s-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.5
        C324.1,403.5,324,403.3,324,403z M324.6,401.2c-0.2,0.1-0.2,0.4-0.2,1s0.1,1,0.2,1.2s0.3,0.5,0.6,0.6c0.3,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.6,0.1
        s0.2-0.4,0.2-1c0-0.5-0.1-1-0.2-1.2s-0.3-0.5-0.6-0.6S324.7,401.1,324.6,401.2z"/>
    <path class="analytics14" d="M190.2,318.8V318l4.1,2.4v0.7l-2.6,4.8l-0.7-0.4l2.6-4.8L190.2,318.8z"/>
    <path class="analytics14" d="M197.3,329.3c-1.6-0.9-2.4-2.5-2.4-5c0-2.4,0.8-3.1,2.4-2.2c1.6,0.9,2.4,2.5,2.4,5
        C199.7,329.4,198.9,330.2,197.3,329.3z M195.6,324.7c0,0.5,0,1,0.1,1.3c0.1,0.4,0.2,0.7,0.3,1s0.3,0.5,0.4,0.7
        c0.2,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.4,0.5c0.1,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.3c0.2,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.2c0.1,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.4,0c0.2,0,0.3-0.1,0.4-0.3
        c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.4,0.3-0.7c0.1-0.3,0.1-0.7,0.1-1.2c0-0.6-0.1-1.1-0.2-1.6s-0.2-0.9-0.4-1.1c-0.2-0.3-0.3-0.5-0.5-0.7
        s-0.4-0.3-0.6-0.4c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.6-0.3c-0.2,0-0.3,0-0.5,0.1s-0.3,0.3-0.4,0.7C195.6,323.6,195.6,324.1,195.6,324.7z"/>
    <path class="analytics14" d="M200.6,326c0-0.4,0-0.7,0.1-0.9c0.1-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.3-0.4s0.3-0.1,0.4,0c0.1,0,0.3,0.1,0.4,0.2
        c0.3,0.2,0.7,0.5,0.9,1c0.3,0.4,0.4,1,0.4,1.7c0,0.4,0,0.7-0.1,0.9c-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3,0.4s-0.3,0.1-0.4,0.1
        c-0.1,0-0.3-0.1-0.4-0.2c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4-0.3s-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.5c-0.1-0.2-0.3-0.5-0.3-0.8C200.7,326.7,200.6,326.4,200.6,326z
         M201.3,325.3c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.4-0.2,1c0,0.5,0.1,1,0.2,1.2c0.2,0.3,0.3,0.5,0.6,0.6s0.4,0.2,0.6,0.1c0.2-0.1,0.2-0.4,0.2-1
        s-0.1-1-0.2-1.2c-0.2-0.3-0.3-0.5-0.6-0.6C201.7,325.2,201.5,325.2,201.3,325.3z M201.7,331.7l3.8-4.9l0.6,0.3l-3.8,4.9
        L201.7,331.7z M204.6,332.4c-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.7-0.1-1c0-0.4,0-0.7,0.1-0.9c0.1-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.3-0.4s0.3-0.1,0.4-0.1
        c0.1,0,0.3,0.1,0.4,0.2c0.2,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.4,0.3s0.3,0.3,0.4,0.5c0.1,0.2,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.8s0.1,0.7,0.1,1c0,0.4,0,0.7-0.1,0.9
        c-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3,0.4s-0.3,0.1-0.4,0.1c-0.1,0-0.3-0.1-0.4-0.2c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4-0.3s-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.5
        C204.8,332.9,204.7,332.7,204.6,332.4z M205.2,330.6c-0.2,0.1-0.2,0.4-0.2,1c0,0.5,0.1,1,0.2,1.2c0.2,0.3,0.3,0.5,0.6,0.6
        s0.4,0.2,0.6,0.1c0.2-0.1,0.2-0.4,0.2-1c0-0.5-0.1-1-0.2-1.2c-0.2-0.3-0.3-0.5-0.6-0.6C205.6,330.6,205.4,330.5,205.2,330.6z"/>
    <path class="analytics10" d="M374.2,439.5v-0.7c0.3,0.4,0.6,0.8,1,1s0.6,0.3,0.8,0.1c0.2-0.1,0.3-0.4,0.3-0.9v-4.4l0.6,0.3v4.5
        c0,0.4,0,0.7-0.1,0.9c-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.4,0.4s-0.3,0-0.5,0s-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.2C374.9,440.3,374.5,439.9,374.2,439.5z"/>
    <path class="analytics10" d="M377.6,440.3c0-0.2,0-0.4,0.1-0.5s0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.4-0.1s0.3,0,0.4,0.1s0.3,0.1,0.4,0.2
        c0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.3,0.2c0.1,0,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1l0.6,0.4c0-0.4-0.1-0.8-0.3-1.1c-0.2-0.3-0.5-0.6-0.9-0.8c-0.4-0.3-0.8-0.4-1.2-0.4
        v-0.7c0.4,0.1,0.8,0.2,1.2,0.4c0.6,0.3,1,0.7,1.3,1.2s0.4,1.1,0.4,1.7v1.4c0,0.3-0.1,0.5-0.2,0.7s-0.3,0.2-0.5,0.2
        s-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.1c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.2c-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4-0.3c-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4-0.4s-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.5s-0.2-0.4-0.3-0.6
        C377.7,440.8,377.6,440.5,377.6,440.3z M378.2,440.6c0,0.6,0.4,1.1,1.1,1.5l0,0c0.7,0.4,1.1,0.3,1.1-0.3V441
        c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.3-0.7-0.5C378.7,440,378.2,440,378.2,440.6z"/>
    <path class="analytics10" d="M381.9,444.2v-4.4c0.5,0,1.1,0.2,1.7,0.5c0.5,0.3,0.9,0.7,1.2,1.1c0.3,0.5,0.4,1,0.4,1.5v3.1l-0.6-0.3v-3.1
        c0-0.1,0-0.3,0-0.4s-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.4c-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.3-0.5c-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.3-0.6-0.4c-0.3-0.2-0.7-0.3-1-0.4v4L381.9,444.2z"/>
    <path class="analytics10" d="M386.1,444.7v-2.8l0.6,0.3v2.8c0,0.5,0.1,0.9,0.3,1.2c0.2,0.3,0.4,0.6,0.8,0.8c0.4,0.2,0.7,0.3,0.8,0.2
        c0.2-0.1,0.3-0.4,0.3-0.9v-2.8l0.6,0.3v2.8c0,0.7-0.2,1.1-0.4,1.3c-0.3,0.2-0.7,0.1-1.2-0.2c-0.5-0.3-1-0.7-1.2-1.3
        C386.2,445.9,386.1,445.3,386.1,444.7z"/>
    <path class="analytics10" d="M390.2,447.5c0-0.2,0-0.4,0.1-0.5s0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.4-0.1s0.3,0,0.4,0.1
        c0.1,0,0.3,0.1,0.4,0.2c0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.3,0.2c0.1,0,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1l0.6,0.4c0-0.4-0.1-0.8-0.3-1.1c-0.2-0.3-0.5-0.6-0.9-0.8
        c-0.4-0.3-0.8-0.4-1.2-0.4v-0.7c0.4,0.1,0.8,0.2,1.2,0.4c0.6,0.3,1,0.7,1.3,1.2s0.4,1.1,0.4,1.7v1.4c0,0.3-0.1,0.5-0.2,0.7
        s-0.3,0.2-0.5,0.2s-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.1c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.2c-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4-0.3c-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4-0.4s-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.5
        s-0.2-0.4-0.3-0.6C390.2,448.1,390.2,447.8,390.2,447.5z M390.8,447.9c0,0.6,0.4,1.1,1.1,1.5l0,0c0.7,0.4,1.1,0.3,1.1-0.3v-0.9
        c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.3-0.7-0.5C391.3,447.2,390.8,447.3,390.8,447.9z"/>
    <path class="analytics10" d="M394.4,451.4V447c0.6,0.1,1.3,0.3,2,0.7v0.6c-0.4-0.3-0.9-0.4-1.4-0.5v3.9L394.4,451.4z"/>
    <path class="analytics10" d="M396.7,448l0.6,0.3l1.1,4.4l1.2-3.1l0.6,0.3l-1.7,4.3c-0.3,0.8-0.7,1-1.3,0.6c-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4-0.3V454
        c0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.3,0.3c0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3,0c0.1,0,0.2-0.1,0.3-0.2c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.2-0.3c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.1-0.3v-0.1
        L396.7,448z"/>
    <path class="analytics15" d="M250.8,345.8c0-0.6,0.2-1.1,0.5-1.4s0.9-0.2,1.7,0.1v-1.4l0.6,0.3v1.4c0.6,0.4,1.2,0.9,1.8,1.6v1
        c-0.6-0.7-1.1-1.2-1.8-1.6v3.1c0.3,0.3,0.6,0.6,0.8,0.9s0.4,0.5,0.7,0.9c0.3,0.3,0.4,0.7,0.5,1.1s0.2,0.8,0.2,1.2
        c0,0.7-0.2,1.1-0.6,1.3c-0.4,0.2-1,0.1-1.7-0.2v1.4l-0.6-0.3v-1.4c-0.8-0.5-1.5-1.1-2.1-1.9v-1.1c0.6,0.8,1.3,1.5,2.1,2v-3.5
        c-0.3-0.3-0.5-0.5-0.7-0.6s-0.3-0.3-0.6-0.6c-0.2-0.3-0.4-0.5-0.5-0.7s-0.2-0.5-0.3-0.8C250.8,346.3,250.8,346,250.8,345.8z
         M251.6,346.2c0,0.3,0.1,0.7,0.3,1s0.6,0.7,1,1.1v-2.9C252.1,345.1,251.6,345.4,251.6,346.2z M253.6,353.2c1,0.4,1.4,0.2,1.4-0.6
        c0-0.5-0.1-0.9-0.4-1.3c-0.3-0.4-0.6-0.8-1.1-1.3L253.6,353.2L253.6,353.2z"/>
    <path class="analytics15" d="M257.3,351.3l0.4-4l4,2.3v1l-3.3-1.9l-0.2,2.6c0.4,0.1,1,0.3,1.5,0.6c0.3,0.2,0.6,0.4,0.9,0.6
        s0.5,0.5,0.8,0.9c0.3,0.3,0.4,0.8,0.6,1.2c0.2,0.5,0.2,1,0.2,1.6c0,0.5-0.1,1-0.2,1.3c-0.2,0.3-0.3,0.5-0.6,0.5
        c-0.3,0.1-0.5,0.1-0.8,0s-0.5-0.2-0.9-0.4c-0.9-0.5-1.6-1.1-2.2-1.8v-1c0.6,0.7,1.3,1.4,2.2,1.9c0.3,0.2,0.6,0.3,0.8,0.3
        c0.2,0,0.4,0,0.5,0c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3c0.1-0.2,0.1-0.3,0.1-0.4s0-0.3,0-0.5c0-0.4,0-0.8-0.1-1.1c-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.6-0.4-0.8
        c-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.4-0.5-0.5c-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.3-0.6-0.4c-0.3-0.2-0.7-0.4-1-0.5s-0.5-0.2-0.6-0.2H258L257.3,351.3z"/>
    <path class="analytics15" d="M266.5,361.7c-2-1.2-3.1-3.3-3.1-6.4s1-4.1,3.1-2.9c2,1.2,3.1,3.3,3.1,6.4
        C269.6,361.9,268.6,362.8,266.5,361.7z M264.3,355.7c0,0.6,0,1.2,0.1,1.7s0.2,1,0.3,1.3c0.1,0.3,0.3,0.7,0.5,0.9
        c0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.6s0.4,0.3,0.6,0.4s0.4,0.2,0.6,0.3c0.2,0.1,0.4,0.1,0.6,0s0.4-0.2,0.5-0.3c0.1-0.2,0.3-0.5,0.3-0.9
        s0.1-1,0.1-1.6c0-0.8-0.1-1.5-0.2-2.1s-0.3-1.1-0.5-1.5s-0.5-0.7-0.7-0.9c-0.2-0.2-0.5-0.4-0.8-0.6s-0.6-0.3-0.8-0.3
        s-0.4,0-0.7,0.1c-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.4-0.5,0.9C264.4,354.3,264.3,354.9,264.3,355.7z"/>
    <path class="analytics15" d="M271,359.2l0.4-4l4,2.3v1l-3.3-1.9l-0.2,2.6c0.4,0.1,1,0.3,1.5,0.6c0.3,0.2,0.6,0.4,0.9,0.6s0.5,0.5,0.8,0.9
        c0.3,0.3,0.4,0.8,0.6,1.2c0.2,0.5,0.2,1,0.2,1.6c0,0.5-0.1,1-0.2,1.3c-0.2,0.3-0.3,0.5-0.6,0.5c-0.3,0-0.5,0.1-0.8,0
        s-0.5-0.2-0.9-0.4c-0.9-0.5-1.6-1.1-2.2-1.8v-1c0.6,0.7,1.3,1.4,2.2,1.9c0.3,0.2,0.6,0.3,0.8,0.3s0.4,0,0.5,0
        c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3s0.1-0.3,0.1-0.4s0-0.3,0-0.5c0-0.4,0-0.8-0.1-1.1s-0.2-0.6-0.4-0.8c-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.4-0.5-0.5
        c-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.3-0.6-0.4c-0.3-0.2-0.7-0.4-1-0.5s-0.5-0.2-0.6-0.2h-0.2L271,359.2z"/>
    <path class="analytics15" d="M277.5,367.9v-1.1l0.8,0.5v1.1L277.5,367.9z"/>
    <path class="analytics15" d="M283,371.2c-2-1.2-3.1-3.3-3.1-6.4s1-4.1,3.1-2.9c2,1.2,3.1,3.3,3.1,6.4S285.1,372.4,283,371.2z M280.8,365.2
        c0,0.6,0,1.2,0.1,1.7s0.2,1,0.3,1.3c0.1,0.3,0.3,0.7,0.5,0.9c0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.6c0.2,0.2,0.4,0.3,0.6,0.4s0.4,0.2,0.6,0.3
        c0.2,0.1,0.4,0.1,0.6,0c0.2,0,0.4-0.2,0.5-0.3c0.1-0.2,0.3-0.5,0.3-0.9c0.1-0.4,0.1-1,0.1-1.6c0-0.8-0.1-1.5-0.2-2.1
        s-0.3-1.1-0.5-1.5s-0.5-0.7-0.7-0.9c-0.2-0.2-0.5-0.4-0.8-0.6s-0.6-0.3-0.8-0.3c-0.2,0-0.4,0-0.7,0.1c-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.4-0.5,0.9
        C280.9,363.8,280.8,364.5,280.8,365.2z"/>
    <path class="analytics15" d="M286.9,370.6v-1l3.7-3.2l1,0.5v5.5l1.1,0.6v0.9l-1.1-0.6v2.7l-0.8-0.5v-2.7L286.9,370.6z M287.9,370.2
        l2.8,1.6v-4L287.9,370.2z"/>
    <path class="analytics12" d="M252.1,368.7v-6.4l3.3,1.9v0.6l-2.7-1.6v2.2l2.4,1.4v0.7l-2.4-1.4v2.9L252.1,368.7z"/>
    <path class="analytics12" d="M255.8,368.5L255.8,368.5L255.8,368.5c0-1.7,0.6-2.2,1.8-1.5c0.3,0.1,0.5,0.3,0.7,0.5s0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6
        c0.1,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.3,0.7c0.1,0.3,0.2,0.4,0.2,0.6s0.1,0.3,0.1,0.6c0,0.2,0,0.3,0,0.4v0.2v0.3l-3-1.7c0,0.5,0.2,0.9,0.4,1.3
        c0.2,0.3,0.5,0.6,1,0.9c0.6,0.3,1,0.5,1.4,0.4v0.7c-0.4,0-0.9-0.2-1.4-0.5l0,0c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.3-0.6-0.5s-0.4-0.4-0.6-0.7
        c-0.2-0.3-0.3-0.6-0.4-1C255.8,369.4,255.8,369,255.8,368.5z M256.3,368.6l2.4,1.4c0-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.4c0-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.6
        c-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.3-0.7c-0.2-0.3-0.4-0.4-0.7-0.6c-0.4-0.2-0.7-0.3-0.9-0.1C256.5,367.7,256.4,368,256.3,368.6z"/>
    <path class="analytics12" d="M260.1,371.9v-5.2l0.6,0.3v1.9c0.3,0.1,0.7,0.2,1,0.4c0.2,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.3s0.3,0.3,0.5,0.5
        s0.3,0.4,0.4,0.7c0.1,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.9c0.1,0.3,0.1,0.7,0.1,1.1s0,0.8-0.1,1c-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.4-0.3,0.5c-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.2-0.4,0.2
        s-0.3,0-0.5-0.1s-0.3-0.1-0.4-0.2c-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.3-0.8-0.6c-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.4-0.5-0.6s-0.2-0.3-0.3-0.5c-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.4
        C260.1,372.1,260.1,372,260.1,371.9z M260.7,372.2c0,0.6,0.3,1,1.1,1.5c0.2,0.1,0.3,0.2,0.4,0.2s0.3,0,0.4,0s0.2-0.2,0.3-0.4
        c0.1-0.2,0.1-0.5,0.1-1c0-0.6-0.1-1.1-0.3-1.5c-0.2-0.4-0.5-0.7-1-1c-0.3-0.2-0.7-0.3-1-0.3V372.2L260.7,372.2z"/>
    <path class="analytics12" d="M264.3,375.7v-4.4c0.6,0.1,1.3,0.3,2,0.7v0.6c-0.4-0.3-0.9-0.4-1.4-0.5v3.9L264.3,375.7z"/>
    <path class="analytics12" d="M266.8,375.2v-2.8l0.6,0.3v2.8c0,0.5,0.1,0.9,0.3,1.2c0.2,0.3,0.4,0.6,0.8,0.8c0.4,0.2,0.7,0.3,0.8,0.2
        c0.2-0.1,0.3-0.4,0.3-0.9V374l0.6,0.3v2.8c0,0.7-0.2,1.1-0.4,1.3c-0.3,0.2-0.7,0.1-1.2-0.2c-0.5-0.3-1-0.7-1.2-1.3
        C267,376.4,266.8,375.8,266.8,375.2z"/>
    <path class="analytics12" d="M270.9,378.1c0-0.2,0-0.4,0.1-0.5s0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.4-0.1s0.3,0,0.4,0.1s0.3,0.1,0.4,0.2
        s0.3,0.1,0.3,0.2c0.1,0,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1l0.6,0.4c0-0.4-0.1-0.8-0.3-1.1c-0.2-0.3-0.5-0.6-0.9-0.8c-0.4-0.3-0.8-0.4-1.2-0.4v-0.7
        c0.4,0.1,0.8,0.2,1.2,0.4c0.6,0.3,1,0.7,1.3,1.2s0.4,1.1,0.4,1.7v1.4c0,0.3-0.1,0.5-0.2,0.7s-0.3,0.2-0.5,0.2s-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.1
        c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.2c-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4-0.3c-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4-0.4s-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.5s-0.2-0.4-0.3-0.6
        C270.9,378.6,270.9,378.4,270.9,378.1z M271.5,378.4c0,0.6,0.4,1.1,1.1,1.5l0,0c0.7,0.4,1.1,0.3,1.1-0.3v-0.9
        c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.3-0.7-0.5C272,377.8,271.5,377.8,271.5,378.4z"/>
    <path class="analytics12" d="M275.1,382v-4.4c0.6,0.1,1.3,0.3,2,0.7v0.6c-0.4-0.3-0.9-0.4-1.4-0.5v3.9L275.1,382z"/>
    <path class="analytics12" d="M277.4,378.6l0.6,0.3l1.1,4.4l1.2-3.1l0.6,0.3l-1.7,4.3c-0.3,0.8-0.7,1-1.3,0.6c-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4-0.3
        v-0.6c0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.3,0.3c0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3,0c0.1,0,0.2-0.1,0.3-0.2c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.2-0.3c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.1-0.3v-0.1
        L277.4,378.6z"/>
    <path class="analytics15" d="M131.6,277.7c0-0.6,0.2-1.1,0.5-1.4s0.9-0.2,1.7,0.1V275l0.6,0.3v1.4c0.6,0.4,1.2,0.9,1.8,1.6v1
        c-0.6-0.7-1.1-1.2-1.8-1.6v3.1c0.3,0.3,0.6,0.6,0.8,0.9s0.4,0.5,0.7,0.9c0.3,0.3,0.4,0.7,0.5,1.1s0.2,0.8,0.2,1.2
        c0,0.7-0.2,1.1-0.6,1.3c-0.4,0.2-1,0.1-1.7-0.2v1.4l-0.6-0.3v-1.4c-0.8-0.5-1.5-1.1-2.1-1.9v-1.1c0.6,0.8,1.3,1.5,2.1,2v-3.5
        c-0.3-0.3-0.5-0.5-0.7-0.6c-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.3-0.6-0.6c-0.2-0.3-0.4-0.5-0.5-0.7s-0.2-0.5-0.3-0.8C131.6,278.3,131.6,278,131.6,277.7
        z M132.4,278.2c0,0.3,0.1,0.7,0.3,1s0.6,0.7,1,1.1v-2.9C132.9,277.1,132.4,277.4,132.4,278.2z M134.4,285.1c1,0.4,1.4,0.2,1.4-0.6
        c0-0.5-0.1-0.9-0.4-1.3c-0.3-0.4-0.6-0.8-1.1-1.3L134.4,285.1L134.4,285.1z"/>
    <path class="analytics15" d="M137.5,279.7v-1l5.3,3.1v0.9l-3.3,6.3l-0.9-0.5l3.4-6.2L137.5,279.7z"/>
    <path class="analytics15" d="M143.9,291.1v-1c0.6,0.8,1.3,1.3,2,1.7s1.2,0.5,1.6,0.4c0.3-0.1,0.5-0.4,0.5-1s-0.2-1.1-0.5-1.6
        c-0.4-0.5-0.9-1-1.6-1.4l-0.9-0.5v-1l0.9,0.5c0.6,0.3,1,0.4,1.3,0.4c0.3-0.1,0.4-0.3,0.4-0.8s-0.2-0.9-0.5-1.4s-0.8-0.8-1.4-1.2
        c-0.6-0.3-1.1-0.5-1.7-0.5v-1c0.5,0,1.1,0.2,1.7,0.5l0,0c0.9,0.5,1.5,1.1,1.9,1.8c0.4,0.7,0.6,1.4,0.6,2.1c0,0.8-0.3,1.2-0.8,1.2
        h-0.2c0,0,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2s0.2,0.2,0.3,0.4s0.3,0.5,0.4,0.7c0.1,0.2,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.9c0.1,0.3,0.2,0.7,0.2,1s-0.1,0.6-0.2,0.9
        c-0.1,0.3-0.3,0.4-0.5,0.6c-0.2,0.1-0.5,0.2-0.9,0.1s-0.8-0.3-1.3-0.5C145.3,292.4,144.6,291.8,143.9,291.1z"/>
    <path class="analytics15" d="M150.4,294.8v-1c0.6,0.8,1.3,1.3,2,1.7c0.7,0.4,1.2,0.5,1.6,0.4c0.3-0.1,0.5-0.4,0.5-1s-0.2-1.1-0.5-1.6
        c-0.4-0.5-0.9-1-1.6-1.4l-0.9-0.5v-1l0.9,0.5c0.6,0.3,1,0.4,1.3,0.4c0.3-0.1,0.4-0.3,0.4-0.8s-0.2-0.9-0.5-1.4
        c-0.3-0.4-0.8-0.8-1.4-1.2c-0.6-0.3-1.1-0.5-1.7-0.5v-1c0.5,0,1.1,0.2,1.7,0.5l0,0c0.9,0.5,1.5,1.1,1.9,1.8
        c0.4,0.7,0.6,1.4,0.6,2.1c0,0.8-0.3,1.2-0.8,1.2h-0.2c0,0,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2c0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.3,0.4c0.2,0.2,0.3,0.5,0.4,0.7
        c0.1,0.2,0.2,0.5,0.3,0.9c0.1,0.3,0.2,0.7,0.2,1s-0.1,0.6-0.2,0.9c-0.1,0.3-0.3,0.4-0.5,0.6c-0.2,0.1-0.5,0.2-0.9,0.1
        s-0.8-0.3-1.3-0.5S151,295.5,150.4,294.8z"/>
    <path class="analytics15" d="M156.7,298.9v-1.1l0.8,0.5v1.1L156.7,298.9z"/>
    <path class="analytics15" d="M159.3,300.4v-0.9c0.4-0.1,0.8-0.3,1.2-0.4c0.4-0.2,0.8-0.4,1.3-0.7c0.4-0.3,0.8-0.6,1.1-1s0.4-0.9,0.4-1.3
        c0-1-0.6-1.9-1.8-2.6c-0.7-0.4-1.4-0.5-2-0.4V292c0.6-0.1,1.3,0.1,2.1,0.5c0.9,0.5,1.5,1.1,1.9,1.9c0.4,0.7,0.6,1.5,0.6,2.2
        c0,0.5-0.1,1-0.3,1.4s-0.5,0.8-0.9,1.1c-0.3,0.3-0.7,0.5-1.1,0.8c-0.3,0.2-0.7,0.4-1.1,0.5l3.5,2v1L159.3,300.4z"/>
    <path class="analytics15" d="M165,301v-1l3.7-3.2l1,0.5v5.4l1.1,0.6v0.9l-1.1-0.6v2.7l-0.8-0.5v-2.7L165,301z M165.9,300.6l2.8,1.6v-4
        L165.9,300.6z"/>
    <path class="analytics14" d="M132.9,300.7v-6.4l0.6,0.4l1.8,4.3l1.9-2.2l0.6,0.4v6.4l-0.6-0.3V298l-1.9,2.1l-1.9-4.4v5.2L132.9,300.7z"/>
    <path class="analytics14" d="M138.8,302.6c0-0.2,0-0.4,0.1-0.5s0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.4-0.1s0.3,0,0.4,0.1
        c0.1,0,0.3,0.1,0.4,0.2c0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.3,0.2c0.1,0,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1l0.6,0.4c0-0.4-0.1-0.8-0.3-1.1s-0.5-0.6-0.9-0.8
        c-0.4-0.3-0.8-0.4-1.2-0.4v-0.7c0.4,0.1,0.8,0.2,1.2,0.4c0.6,0.3,1,0.7,1.3,1.2s0.4,1.1,0.4,1.7v1.4c0,0.3-0.1,0.5-0.2,0.7
        c-0.1,0.2-0.3,0.2-0.5,0.2s-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.1c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.1-0.5-0.2c-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4-0.3s-0.3-0.2-0.4-0.4
        c-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.5s-0.2-0.4-0.3-0.6C138.8,303.1,138.8,302.9,138.8,302.6z M139.4,303c0,0.6,0.4,1.1,1.1,1.5l0,0
        c0.7,0.4,1.1,0.3,1.1-0.3v-0.9c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.3-0.7-0.5C139.9,302.3,139.4,302.4,139.4,303z"/>
    <path class="analytics14" d="M143,306.5v-4.4c0.6,0.1,1.3,0.3,2,0.7v0.6c-0.4-0.3-0.9-0.4-1.4-0.5v3.9L143,306.5z"/>
    <path class="analytics14" d="M145.3,305.5c0-0.5,0.1-0.9,0.2-1.1c0.1-0.3,0.3-0.4,0.5-0.5s0.4-0.1,0.6,0c0.2,0,0.4,0.1,0.7,0.3
        c0.4,0.2,0.8,0.5,1.2,1v0.6c-0.4-0.4-0.7-0.7-1.1-0.9c-0.5-0.3-0.8-0.3-1-0.2c-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.5-0.3,1.2c0,0.6,0.1,1.2,0.3,1.6
        s0.6,0.8,1,1s0.8,0.3,1.1,0.4v0.7c-0.4,0-0.8-0.2-1.2-0.4c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.5-0.3c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.3-0.5-0.5s-0.3-0.4-0.4-0.7
        c-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.3-0.9C145.4,306.2,145.3,305.9,145.3,305.5z"/>
    <path class="analytics14" d="M149.1,310.1v-6.6l0.6,0.3v2c0.4,0,0.8,0.2,1.2,0.4c0.5,0.3,0.9,0.7,1.1,1.2c0.3,0.5,0.4,1.1,0.4,1.7v2.8
        l-0.6-0.3v-2.8c0-0.9-0.3-1.5-1-1.9c-0.4-0.2-0.8-0.3-1.1-0.4v3.9L149.1,310.1z"/>
</g>
</g>
<g>
    <circle class="analytics23" cx="38.8" cy="76.8" r="7"/>
    <circle class="analytics23" cx="511.8" cy="465.8" r="5"/>
    <circle class="analytics24" cx="130.8" cy="470.8" r="10"/>
    <circle class="analytics25" cx="480.8" cy="69.8" r="10"/>
</g>
</svg>
  </div>
```

You may also want to `translate` it.